# Create new variables file and include it after that in the same makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I want to create config file if it's missing out of template when I do make and then include it for further export of these variables. This code is working if `.env` file exist, however it doesn't if try to create this file inside this script. If I remove the last 2 lines from the script, the `.env` file is successfully copied.

```bash
ifndef ENV
override ENV = .env
endif

all:

ifneq (,$(wildcard $(ENV)))
    $(info **************  Reading environment variables from $(ENV) **************)
else
    $(warning !!!!!!!!!!!!! $(ENV) environmint config file is not found !!!!!!!!!!!!!)
    $(info ************** Creating .env file and substitute variables **************)
    cp $(CURDIR)/.env.example  $(CURDIR)/.env
endif

include $(ENV)
export
```

Comment: Just add a rule to create/update `$(ENV)` .  Something like `$(ENV): $(CURDIR)/.env.example` ?

Comment: sorry, didn't get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the problem but I suspect you're just looking for a `makefile` rule that creates/updates `$(ENV)`...

```
$(ENV): $(CURDIR)/.env.example
    cp $< $@
```

**Edit**: Some explanation as requested in the comments.

Although you refer to the file in question as a 'config' file, the fact that it's included in your `makefile` via...

```
include $(ENV)
```

means, of course, that it is in fact a `makefile` itself.  That being the case this is covered by ["How Makefiles Are Remade"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles).

Basically, when `make` sees a file in an `include` directive it will look to see if it knows of any rules to update that file.  If it does then it will invoke that rule before running the `include` directive.  That way you can achieve a 'just-in-time' (sort of) update of the target in question.

Comment: I want `.env.example` file to be copied to the `.env` file and then all variables from that file to be exported

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Have you tried what I've shown?  The existing `include $(ENV)` line in your `makefile` should trigger the rule in the code I've provided.  Hence the `$(ENV)` file should be created/updated *before* it's included.

Comment: ok, it's working. It would be nice if you explain that magic :)